# Multiple Attachments

Tags: list, list-item, attachments, item-attachment

I am creating a SharePoint list gathering travel information from users.  This will require adding multiple attachments to be submitted.  Is there a way to add all the attachments in one upload?  Currently it is only allowing me to add one at a time.

Comment: not unless you use a Document Library or Document Set or build something custom

Comment: @Colbs, I'll try using a Document Library.  Thanks.